# Cannot get the correct printer status

Tags: windows, delphi, printing

I am using Delphi 10.3 to create a program that prints labels with barcodes. I do not want the printer to queue multiple jobs instead i want to start printing the next job after the previous is finished and receive ready status from the printer. The status of the printer is always ready, even if it is offline!

I use this functions to get the status of the printer:

```
function TPrintQRForm.GetCurrentPrinterHandle() : THandle;
var
  Device, Driver, Port : Array[0..255] of Char;
  hDeviceMode : THandle;

begin
  Printer.GetPrinter(Device, Driver, Port, hDeviceMode);

  if not Winspool.OpenPrinter(@Device, Result, nil) then
  begin
    RaiseLastOSError();
  end;
end;

function TPrintQRForm.GetCurrentPrinterInformation() : TPrinterInfo;
var
  hPrinter : THandle;
  pInfo : PPrinterInfo2;
  bytesNeeded : DWORD;

begin
  hPrinter := GetCurrentPrinterHandle();
  try
    Winspool.GetPrinter(hPrinter, 2, Nil, 0, @bytesNeeded);
    pInfo := AllocMem(bytesNeeded);

    try
      Winspool.GetPrinter(hPrinter, 2, pInfo, bytesNeeded, @bytesNeeded);
      Result.ServerName := pInfo^.pServerName;
      Result.PrinterName := pInfo^.pPrinterName;
      Result.ShareName := pInfo^.pShareName;
      Result.PortName := pInfo^.pPortName;
      Result.DriverName := pInfo^.pDriverName;
      Result.Comment := pInfo^.pComment;
      Result.Location := pInfo^.pLocation;
      Result.DeviceMode := pInfo^.pDevMode;
      Result.SepFile := pInfo^.pSepFile;
      Result.PrintProcessor := pInfo^.pPrintProcessor;
      Result.DataType := pInfo^.pDatatype;
      Result.Parameters := pInfo^.pParameters;
      Result.SecurityDescriptor := pInfo^.pSecurityDescriptor;
      Result.Attributes := pInfo^.Attributes;
      Result.DefaultPriority := pInfo^.DefaultPriority;
      Result.StartTime := pInfo^.StartTime;
      Result.UntilTime := pInfo^.UntilTime;
      Result.Status := pInfo^.Status;
      Result.Jobs := pInfo^.cJobs;
      Result.AveragePPM := pInfo^.AveragePPM;
    finally
      FreeMem(pInfo);
    end;
  finally
    ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
  end;
end;
```

And then on a certain event i check for printer status using this code:

```
  PrinterInfo := GetCurrentPrinterInformation();

  while PrinterInfo.Status <> 0 do
  begin
    if PrinterInfo.Status = PRINTER_STATUS_PRINTING then
    begin
      // Get information about the selected printer
      PrinterInfo := GetCurrentPrinterInformation();
      
      // Process messages from the OS and do not freeze the UI
      Application.ProcessMessages;

      Continue;
    end;

    Case PrinterInfo.Status of
      PRINTER_STATUS_PAUSED             : ShowMessage('The printer is paused.');
      PRINTER_STATUS_ERROR              : ShowMessage('The printer is in an error state.');
      PRINTER_STATUS_PENDING_DELETION   : ShowMessage('The printer is being deleted.');
      PRINTER_STATUS_PAPER_JAM          : ShowMessage('Paper is jammed in the printer.');
      PRINTER_STATUS_PAPER_OUT          : ShowMessage('The printer is out of paper.');
      PRINTER_STATUS_MANUAL_FEED        : ShowMessage('The printer is in a manual feed state.');
      PRINTER_STATUS_PAPER_PROBLEM      : ShowMessage('The printer has a paper problem.');
      PRINTER_STATUS_OFFLINE            : ShowMessage('The printer is offline.');
      PRINTER_STATUS_IO_ACTIVE          : ShowMessage('The printer is in an active input/output state.');
      PRINTER_STATUS_BUSY               : ShowMessage('The printer is busy.');
      PRINTER_STATUS_OUTPUT_BIN_FULL    : ShowMessage('The printer''s output bin is full.');
      PRINTER_STATUS_NOT_AVAILABLE      : ShowMessage('The printer is not available for printing.');
      PRINTER_STATUS_WAITING            : ShowMessage('The printer is waiting.');
      PRINTER_STATUS_PROCESSING         : ShowMessage('The printer is processing a print job.');
      PRINTER_STATUS_INITIALIZING       : ShowMessage('The printer is initializing.');
      PRINTER_STATUS_WARMING_UP         : ShowMessage('The printer is warming up.');
      PRINTER_STATUS_TONER_LOW          : ShowMessage('The printer is low on toner.');
      PRINTER_STATUS_NO_TONER           : ShowMessage('The printer is out of toner.');
      PRINTER_STATUS_PAGE_PUNT          : ShowMessage('The printer cannot print the current page.');
      PRINTER_STATUS_USER_INTERVENTION  : ShowMessage('The printer has an error that requires the user to do something.');
      PRINTER_STATUS_OUT_OF_MEMORY      : ShowMessage('The printer has run out of memory.');
      PRINTER_STATUS_DOOR_OPEN          : ShowMessage('The printer door is open.');
      PRINTER_STATUS_POWER_SAVE         : ShowMessage('The printer is in power save mode.');
     else
       ShowMessage('The error  is unknown');
     end;

     Exit;
  end;
```

After this code i start the printing process and everything is in a loop for all the copies i need to print.

I am using a TSC-TPP 2410M printer and it never gives printing status although it queues the jobs. So the code never goes inside the while because i am always getting 0 printer status.

Is there any way to disable the queue or to make the app wait for the printer to stop printing and then execute the next print job? Any thoughts?

**EDIT:** After some suggestions from @BlurrySterk i discovered that the printer emits PRINTER_STATUS_PRINTING when the number of jobs in the queue get to 10. After printing all of them it gets ready again.

Comment: I don't a printer's status is always available. Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows/win32/printer-print-job-status

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have already read this article and it says: _"There is one fundamental premise that must be true to determine the state of a physical printer: the Spooler must be attempting to send a print job to the physical printer. This is the only time the state of the printer is reported by the port monitor."_. But i cannot understand how to get the physical printers status... When is the spooler attempting to print?

Comment: The spooler will attempt to print as soon as a print job arrives in the print queue. Obviously the Windows setting that specifies whether a print job must print immediately or only after the last page will affect that. But I suspect that the job goes through the queue so quickly that the status does not change.

Comment: I do not see any code that specifies which printer to get the information for. May I assume that this printer you are testing on is actually the windows default printer?

Comment: Try the `EnumJobs` functionality as described in the article and see if you get any jobs listed. If not then I do think the job goes through the queue too fast

Comment: @Blurry Sterk. The printer is selected from a TPrintDialog. I have tested the code and it returns the correct printer handle in the GetCurrentPrinterHandle. I 'll try the EnumJobs and i 'll let you know. Thank you!

Comment: I see `TPrintQRForm`... Arre you using QuickReports?

Comment: No, i am printing barcodes and QR Code. I use Zint and DelphiZXingQRCode libraries

Comment: The Status in that `PrinterInfo` is possible combinations of Statuses. You are just checking against a single status. Check for combos. Its a bit field

Comment: Windows manages printers.  Users decide whether they use the print spooler or not.  It's not up to you.  To change this for a user is unfriendly behaviour.  Your application would require administrative privileges to make this configuration change on a user's computer.  You should not be changing the user's print spooler setup.  If this is for an embedded application where you have control of the system, disabling the print spooler seems to be what you want to do.

Comment: If you print with ZPL check out my Github...

Comment: @BlurrySterk I tried EnumJobs and it found the jobs in the queue. I m printing thousands of jobs so it is impossible to go that fast all of them. Also PrinterInfo.Status is returning a single status and not a combinations. I get the printing status only when the queue gets 10 jobs... it then prints them while emiting PRINTER_STATUS_PRINTING. It seems to work with batches of ten which is still a problem to me.

Comment: It seems you are limited by what Windows provides you. I am afraid thats the ball game. You might employ other workaround techniques to achieve what you want but I don't think it will be based on any status from the print queue. Maybe you can measure a metric based on how fast the printer outputs a certain sized job and based on that you can estimate how long each job will take to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there are limits to the WinAPI, as mentioned in the comments.

Because the previous printer is dead now, we bought a TSC ME240. There is a programming manual for TSPL/2 commands in this [link](http://www.kroyeuropedownload.com/English_User_Manuals/TSPL_TSPL2_Programming_Jan_2017.pdf).

To solve the problem i connected the printer to the network and send TSPL/2 commands through a tcp socket.

I needed this code to get the status

```
  // Create TCP Client
  TCPClient := TIdTCPClient.Create();

  // Connect to server
  TCPClient.Host := PrinterIP;
  TCPClient.Port := PrinterPort;
  TCPClient.Connect();

  // Set status string
  StatusString := #27 + '!?';

  // Send command
  TCPClient.Socket.WriteLn(StatusString);

  // Check status
  PrinterStatus := TCPClient.Socket.ReadByte;
```

The printer is responding and the job is done. Thanks for all the effort guys/girls.

Comment: Nice solution. I am having the same problem. But I am trying to connect using c#. May I ask what does the #27 represent in Delphi as I can see you are not converting the message to a byte array. Here is my question if you can offer any advice. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68260077/c-sharp-get-tsc-printer-status?noredirect=1#comment120639792_68260077

Comment: It represents the <ESC> character in the ASCII table. In the post there is a link to the TSPL/2 commands manual. In page 79, at the section "Status Polling and Immediate Commands" it says that if you send the <ESC>!? sequence to the printer it responds it's status.